# Rails model has_many , belongs_to relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
 end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Do I need to add a column user_id to the Product table or does rails add it by default ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You do need to manually add the `user_id` column to the `Product` model. If you haven't created your model yet, add the reference in the column list to the model generator. For example:

`rails generate model Product name:string price:decimal user:references`

Or, if your `Product` model already exists what you have to do is:

`rails g migration addUserIdToProducts user_id:integer`

That will generate a migration that properly add the `user_id` column to the `products` table. With the column properly named (user_id), Rails will know that's your foreign key.

Comment: hey, I am using `postgresql` and I did the model creation using the first method you mentioned. using `user:references`. now when I try to delete the `user` model object it gives me `PG::ForeignKeyViolation:` error. My expectation is, all the `products` under the `user` should be deleted when I delete a user. PS: I have `belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy` in my `Product` model.

I am a beginner in rails :)