# generating model with ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Folks,

I am working on creating an application where I have two entities in my problem space. One entity is "biologist" and the other entity is "experiment" now one biologist can have many experiments and each experiment can have many biologist.

I know how to create models and routes using the command line generator:

```
 rails generate scaffold Biologist name:string expertise:string last_pub:text
```

What is the right way to add an association? Is it to go and update the model code after generation? What is unclear to me is if I add a "belongs_to" association post generation how does that reflect in the DB schema without running a migration or something? In the above example if "experiment" belongs to "biologist" then there will be a foreign key in the "biologist" table, how will that be created if I add the associations in the model class post generation. I am fairly new to rails, so I apologize if this is a naive question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a migration to add a `biologist_id` column to the `experiments` table, and then add the `belongs_to :biologist` relationship in your `experiments` model.

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742633/rails-model-has-many-belongs-to-relations/8743097#8743097).

Answer (score 54):

I think you are looking for something like the following:

```
rails g scaffold Biologist experiment:references
```

Read [this article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/) by Jose Valim where he shows you how to do the above, and also add db indexes from the command line:

Comment: Try it yourself `rails g scaffold Biologist title:index email:uniq`. You will see that the code required for creating indexes in automatically added to your migration. It saves a bit of typing, and means that you can just run your migrations and move on.

Comment: ic…I, mistakenly, thought you were suggesting to make changes to the schema directly from command line. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

I would generate a model for each each and then create a join table since you have a has many to has many relationship. If you follow convention properly, rails should understand the relationship given your join table.

In general, if you need to modify active record relationships, you should do it in the model using a has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.