# Rails - Adding existing track to an existing playlist - UPDATED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, playlist

**See update below**

I want to add an existing track to an existing playlist but i am not sure how to approach this.

I have a

- tracks table,
- a playlist table
- and a join table called playlist_tracks.

**FYI - Models pasted below**

I am assuming I need to write a function that will:

listen for a click event on a track

> capture track_id

Ask to choose a playlist

> display existing playlists

> listen for click event on desired playlist

> capture playlist_id

> add track_id and playlist_id into Join Table

Then I should be able to navigate to the playlist SHOW Page and see the track that was added.

At the moment I am going to attempt rendering a simple form dropdown showing playlists on each track and adding a create method in my playlist_tracks controller.

**But if anyone has a better idea or a link to a great resource, I would appreciate it. Will update this post if I progress**

----- Models -----

Playlist Model

```
class Playlist < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :playlist_tracks
    has_many :tracks, through: :playlist_tracks
    has_many :tags, through: :playlist_tags
    belongs_to :user

    validates :playlist_title, presence: true, length: { in: 1..20 }
    validates :playlist_description, presence: true, length: { in: 10..60 }

    has_one_attached :photo
end
```

Tracks model

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :album
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :playlist_tracks
    has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_tracks
    has_many :tags, through: :tags_tracks

    validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 1..20 }
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { in: 10..60 }
    has_one_attached :photo
    has_one_attached :track
end
```

PlaylistTrack Model

```
class PlaylistTrack < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :playlist
end
```

Comment: This is what you want, [has_many, belongs_to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743097/9052234). If you have tables already then you can add relation with a migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I managed to get some help from a mentor. We decided the first easiest route to take was to include a simple form on each track card with a dropdown menu containing collection of playlists.

Form and controller below

Form

```
<%= simple_form_for @playlist_track, url: playlist_tracks_path, method: :post do |f| %>
<%= f.association :playlist, :collection => Playlist.all, label_method: :playlist_title %>
<%= f.input :track_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: track.id } %>
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class PlaylistTracksController < ApplicationController
    def create
    @playlist_track = PlaylistTrack.new(playlist_track_params)
        if @playlist_track.save!
            redirect_to station_index_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def playlist_track_params
        params.require(:playlist_track).permit(:track_id, :playlist_id)
    end
end
```

I can now add a track to an existing playlist :)